# Dimension of Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

*This problem is taken from [International Mathematics Competition for University Students 2009](http://imc2009.elte.hu/Problems/imc2009-day2.pdf) (IMC 2009), Day 2, Problem 5.*

---

Let $\mathbb{M}$ be the vector space of $m \times p$ real matrices. For a vector subspace $S \subset \mathbb{M}$, denote $\delta(S)$ the dimesion of the vector space generated by all columns of all matrices in $S$. Say that a vector space $T \subset \mathbb{M}$ is a covering space, if $$ \bigcup\limits_{A \in T, A \neq 0} ker(A) = \mathbb{R}^{p}$$

Such a $T$ is minimal if it does not contain a proper vector subspace $S \subset T$ which is also a covering matrix space. Let $T$ be a minimal covering matrix space and let $n= \text{dim}(T)$. Prove that $$\delta(T) \leq { n \choose 2 } $$

Comment: Could you provide some context for this question?  Is it a homework problem?

Comment: Moreover your title is super general, you should make it more specific.

Comment: @BBischof: Please help me in renaming the title. Like what could i  name it.

Comment: Hehe, I don't see a obviously good name, but maybe something like "Vector Space Dimension Inequality for Covering Matrix Spaces". That is the only one I can come up with at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Problem 5](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2009/imc2009-day2-solutions.pdf)

Comment: Nice.  How in world did you find that?